# Local Cross-origin data error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

I'm trying to make a game in JavaScript and i need to get pixeldata from an image. i'm using getImageData().data; and it is working all good on Internet Explorer, but on Chrome i get this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

I've been looking around for solutions but nothing seems to work, anyone have a good idea?

here is my code: `
var
            width = 600,
            height = 400,
            img,
            canvas,
            ctx;

```
    function main() {
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        init();
        loop();

    }

    function init() {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = "test.png";


    }

    function update() {

    }

    function render() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var data = ctx.getImageData(10, 10, 1, 1).data;
        console.log(data);

    }

    function loop() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        update();
        render();
    }

    main();`
```

The file is running localy and not on a server.

Answer (score 1):

If you load your page or file using file://... it will trigger CORS issues as well.

When testing locally, always use a local server so you can load the files from localhost.

Also a side issue: remember to use the `onload` handler for the image:

```
function init() {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = ...   // don't start loop without it...
    img.src = "test.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
function init() {
    img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.src = "test.png";


}
```